# Bootstrap 4 tabs and ajax javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 tabs to display content that is retrieved from an AJAX call. 
The problem is that I am getting an error when the call has completed.

The error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function
```

The tabs are initially hidden and the result of the AJAX call determines what tabs are displayed and what tab to open on.

The tabs are the standard example :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item hidden">
        <a class="nav-link" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Anotherhome" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Another Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item hidden" id="profile-tab-container">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item hidden">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Anotherhome" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Another Home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact</div>
</div>
```

The AJAX call is also standard. It is called on `$(document).ready` :

```
$.ajax({
    url: _url,
    method: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        // data object gets populated here

        var _profileTab = $("#profile-tab-container");  // <= this is valid - correct object retrieved
        _profileTab.show();                             // <= show the tab on the screen. no error here
        $("#profile-tab").tab("show");                  // <= use the internal bootstrap method to select the tab. error here

    },
    error: function (err) {
        // error handling here;
    }
});
```

If I put a breakpoint on the line that causes the error:

```
$("#profile-tab").tab("show");
```

you can see that the page has got all it's content but the bootstrap styles have not been applied, i.e. no tabs set up. So it may be that the tabs have not been applied by the time the AJAX call completes?

Note. The error occurs on page load, but if I manually call the AJAX function again (via a button) it all works fine.

Is there some way to fire either the entire AJAX call or a display method once the tabs have been applied? Or some other way to display the content and interactions without error?
I don't mind displaying all the content on the page and hiding it after the call is made?

Comment: Have you added a link to `bootstrap.js` in your code?

Comment: "So it may be that the tabs have not been applied by the time the ajax call completes" => Don't think so because the error is `is not a function` but you can try it out by just setting a timeout of a second or whatever before you call your `.tab` function. @dutchess I would be really surprised if he did :D but yes, it could be that he just forgot to include the JS file.

Comment: can you see the order of the files. maybe you have loaded bootstrap before jquery.

Comment: jquery is loaded first, followed by bootstrap.min.js. After the page is loaded everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code work fine.

1. Add all the libraries which are needed.
2. Check your ajax api url and it's response i have used 
   dummy ajax url : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
3. Check agian carefully.

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
       method: "GET",
       success: function (data) {
           // data object gets populated here

           var _profileTab = $("#profile-tab-container");  // <= this is valid - correct object retrieved
           //_profileTab.show();                             // <= show the tab on the screen. no error here
           $("#profile-tab").tab("show");                  // <= use the internal bootstrap method to select the tab. error here

       },
       error: function (err) {
           // error handling here;
       }
    });
   });
   ```

Add libraries in html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, i just write a basic code with dummy ajax url and it's works fine. Please double check your libraries, i think you missed anyone. Try this i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

> **Dummy API [link](https://reqres.in/)**

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2',
    method: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        var _profileTab = $("#profile-tab-container");
        _profileTab.show();
        $("#profile-tab").tab("show");
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item hidden">
        <a class="nav-link" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Anotherhome" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Another Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item hidden" id="profile-tab-container">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item hidden">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Anotherhome" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Another Home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact</div>
</div>

 <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```